# Splitting a list into strings

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I have a variable that contains multiple lists. I'm trying to split the lists into strings so that I can add them to a csv file but I'm not sure how.

This is what I have been trying to do. For some reason, integrating through the different lists (i.e. participants) doesn't seem to work properly. It only uses the last list instead.

```
results = open("results.csv", "w")
strings = ""
for participant in contents:
    for list in participant:
        s = ""
        for x in list:
            s += x
            strings += s
results.write(f"{strings}")
```

Comment: You are shadowing the `list` keyword as a variable.

Comment: `strings += s` is indented 1 block to far.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the contents of `contents` and corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(','.join(s) for s in [participant for participant in contest]))
```